# How to build Android apps without Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

First up, I'm totally new to the Android ecosystem and mobile app dev in general. However I am a veteran C#/C++/JS/Java app and web dev. So currently my corporate firewall has rules to prevent our work PCs from connecting online. I'm supposed to be doing android app dev fully offline. I got Android Studio installed and created a test app, however gradle refuses to build offline, even with the "Offline work" option ticked. If I build an app on my internet-connected laptop all goes fine. If I copy that app to my work PC, gradle crashes with "cannot find module XYZ in gradle cache". I tried copying over the`<user>/.gradle/caches/` dir from my laptop to my PC but that doesn't work either.

So, I'm left with no option but to attempt to build my android project without gradle. I'd like to use the Android Studio IDE if possible, else I'd fallback to SublimeText. So my question is, **how do I build, debug and emulate android apps without gradle?**

Things I've tried:

- Creating a hello world app on my laptop, building it and emulating it. Gradle updates all its libs and stuff, and I used the AVD Manager to download an AVD image an setup an emulator.
- Copying over the test app project dir to my work PC
- Copying over the updated Android SDK dir to my work PC (with the AVD image, etc)
- Copying over the gradle caches to my work PC

Comment: a good justification to work at home :)

Comment: you could try old Eclipse

Comment: Ant may be an option for you (but the configuration time might not be worth it). Offline mode should work after you built it at least once while being connected.

Comment: The most work being done today on offline builds probably is in the world of continuous integration servers, so you can see how they handle it. You could look to see if a different supported build system (e.g., Buck) can handle offline builds.

Comment: Is the stipulations from work that you must build this without any internet access? Or is it that they simply have all access to internet disconnected from everyone period. If that is the case, I would consider asking them if you can connect your workstation to the internet long enough to get all the sdk and such correctly downloaded. Offline mode should work, but I imagine that it will only work if android studio has recognized it has gone online and downloaded the proper sdk and such.

Comment: Furthermore take in mind that without internet you will have also problems to include libraries. You will lose many gradle powers earning many many problems.

Comment: I also want to do my work without the Gradle, it's too heavy and slow. please go back to native IDE, not the Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you need internet connection once for the first build, then you can go to settings & enable offline. then you can build without the internet connection.
Android Studio makes life easier. Anything other than that is going to very hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bmuschko/e4e04abca105c397145e) to download dependencies to a local folder. You can then use:

```
repositories {
   maven {
      url uri('c:/path/to/repo') 
   } 
}
```

To work offline

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: I wrote a series of scripts to build a Java/Kotlin Android app, including dependencies, without Gradle. There's a separate script to download packages, which is configured to look for AndroidX packages by default but you can provide it a full URL instead. After that point, running the other scripts is enough to build the app offline.

Link: https://github.com/jbendtsen/tiny-android-template

Answer (score -1):

You can do it through the Intellij with android plugin, however somewhat unsupported features are still existed.

Mostly I work on Android Studio sometimes I'm using IntelliJ community version. 
please try...